# What is the correct behaviour when setting the cmi.exit variable

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

**Scenario A:** Suppose SCO A sets its `cmi.exit = suspend` and then triggers a Continue navigation request and SCO B is launched. SCO B triggers a Previous navigation request. In this case, should the Tracking Model (Objective Progress Info, Attempt Progress Info, and Activity Progress Info) of SCO A be set to default or not?

**Scenario B:** Suppose SCO A sets its `cmi.exit = normal` and then triggers a Continue navigation request and SCO B is launched. SCO B triggers a Previous navigation request. In this case, should the Tracking Model (Objective Progress Info, Attempt Progress Info, and Activity Progress Info) of SCO A be set to default or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scenario A, all tracking data will be saved on terminating SCO A. When the learner attempts SCO A again, all data is retrieved and SCO A should resume from where the learner was when the Continue Nav request was triggered.

In scenario B, all tracking data of SCO A is set to the default.

Comment: You said `In scenario B, all tracking data of SCO A is set to the default`. Where the Tracking Model of SCO A should be set to the default exactly @FadelMS?

Comment: Could you please give me more information about the location to set the Tracking Model of the activity to the default values? Thank you, @FadelMS.

Comment: In the Content Delivery Environment Process [DB.2] line 5.1.1.2.3. (Initialize Objective Progress Information and Attempt
Progress Information required for the new attempt)

Comment: In the RTE book, it is written "_If the SCO sets cmi.exit to “suspend”, the LMS shall set the “Activity is Suspended” value of the learning activity associated with the SCO to true._". I have a question about this. `Where should I set the "Activity is Suspended" of the activity to true exactly`, @FadelMS?

Comment: In End Attempt Process [UP.4] line 2.1.1. (Set the Activity is Suspended for the activity to True). On terminating an activity, the LMS should check the value of the "cmi.exit" and set the activity's state accordingly.

Comment: But it seems in the line 2.1.1. 'Set the Activity is Suspended for the `activity` to True', the word `activity` refers to a cluster and doesn't refer to a leaf (SCO). Clusters don't have cmi.exit element. Could you please explain more, @FadelMS? Thank you.

Comment: The parent's suspended state depends on its children's suspended state. If a child activity is suspended, its parents up to the root activity must be suspended. You need to include code in the End Attempt Process to check the 'cmi.exit' value to see whether an activity is suspended then update the suspended state of the activity and its parents accordingly.

Comment: Suppose we have an Activity Tree with three activities (i.e., Root Activity with two children SCO A and SCO B). First, SCO A is launched. SCO A sets its 'cmi.exit' to 'suspend' and 'adl.nav.request' to 'continue' and triggers Terminate(). In this case, the 'Activity is Suspended' of SCO A should be set to 'true' and also the 'Activity is Suspended' of Root Activity should be set to 'true'. Then, SCO B is launched. In this case, the 'Activity is Suspended' of SCO B should be set to 'true'. Now, what is the value of the 'Activity is Suspended' of Root Activity?

Comment: In this case, the 'Activity is Suspended' of SCO B should be set to 'true'. No. SCO B will not be suspended, only SCO A and the Root Activity will be suspended. When a parent is suspended, it doesn't meant that all children will be suspended. In fact, the parent is suspended because one or more of its child activities have been suspended, not the other way round.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I corrected my scenario: We have a Tree with 3 activities (i.e., Root Activity with two children SCO A and SCO B). First, SCO A is launched. SCO A sets its 'cmi.exit' to 'suspend' and 'adl.nav.request' to 'continue' and triggers Terminate(). In this case, the 'Activity is Suspended' of SCO A should be set to 'true' and also the 'Activity is Suspended' of Root Activity should be set to 'true'. Then, SCO B is launched. `In this case, the 'Activity is Suspended' of SCO B should be set to 'false'`. Now, what is the value of the 'Activity is Suspended' of Root Activity?

Comment: Now, what is the value of the 'Activity is Suspended' of Root Activity? True.

Comment: Do you mean the root activity is suspended while one of its activities (i.e., SCO B) is active? This is in contradiction with `The parent's suspended state depends on its children's suspended state`. Could you explain this for me, @FadelMS? Thank you.

Comment: Please read this in the 'Sequencing and Navigation' document: Because attempts on activities only occur within the context of an
attempt on their parent (ancestor) activities, if any leaf activity in the Activity
Tree is suspended, the root of the Activity Tree will also be suspended.

Comment: I read the book before and I agree with `attempts on activities only occur within the context of an attempt on their parent (ancestor) activities, if any leaf activity in the Activity Tree is suspended, the root of the Activity Tree will also be suspended`. In fact, my question is: In the above scenario, should the root activity be suspended while one of its children (i.e., SCO B) is active (i.e., Activity is Suspended = false) and the learner is interacting with SCO B?

Comment: If the 'Activity is suspended' for SCO A is 'true' and 'Activity is Suspended' for SCO B is 'false', in this case, what is the value of 'Activity is Suspended' of the root activity?

Comment: what is the value of 'Activity is Suspended' of the root activity? True. It will stay true until all suspended children are cleared.

Comment: Could you give me the Pseudo Code for setting the 'Activity is Suspended' of the activity and its parents up to the root according to the value of 'cmi.exit' at line 2.1.1. of the End Attempt Process, @FadelMS? Thank you so much.